# Vue.js non reactive objects of array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have one problem. I have

```
data: {
        tracks: []
    }
```

And tracks array will contain a complex object. And when I assign a new value to tracks nested object to become reactivity. But I just don't need not deep reactivity object. How can I do it without created function or JSON.parse?

*Because tracks used with Cesium framework and use Vue getter. And FPS becomes 10-15. Without Vue have 50-60 FPS*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `Object.freeze` or `Object.defineProperty` (you only need configurable: false) to prevent Vue from picking up reactivity on large datasets

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cesium-and-vue-js-data-getters/26928

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a deep watcher on tracks:

```
watch: {
  tracks: {
    handler (newVal, oldVal) {
      // implement what you want to do here
      // If you just wanted to force a re-render you can do:
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }
    deep: true,
}
```

Comment: but if I don't want deep watching? it is on default deep watching my objects

Comment: Vue can either observe the entire path of your object by using deep or just the top layer (by default). There is no in between. You can only either trigger $forceUpdate yourself every time or use this.$set() every time you change a nested object in tracks. But what's the reason you don't want to use deep anyway? It's exactly meant for those situations.

Comment: Because tracks used with Cesium framework and use Vue getter. And FPS becomes 10-15. Without Vue have 50-60 FPS

Comment: When I use watch method, I get already array with reactive objects.